# How can I display current user's name on display?

Tags: android

After logging in, I want to display a message that says 'Welcome, (username)!' on the next activity. For now I have absolutely no idea how to implement it. So can somebody give me an advice?

So far, I only managed to implement the signup & login parts.

Here are the code snippets that stores the user data and enable the login.

1. MembershipDatabaseHelper.java

   ```
   public final class MembershipDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
       private static final String DB_NAME = "members.db";
       private static final String DB_TABLE = "members";
       private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
       private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
       private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
       private static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
       private static final String COLUMN_LASTNAME = "lastname";
       private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
       private static final String COLUMN_DOB = "dob";
       private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
       + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
       + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

       private static String queryDrop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE;

       SQLiteDatabase db;

       public MembershipDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
           this.db = db;
       }

       public void signup(User user) {
           db = this.getWritableDatabase();
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

           String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE;
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
           int count = cursor.getCount();

           values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
           values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
           values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, user.getFirstname());
           values.put(COLUMN_LASTNAME, user.getLastname());
           values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
           values.put(COLUMN_DOB, user.getDob());
           db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
           db.close();
       }

       public String searchPassword(String email) {
           db = this.getReadableDatabase();
           String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_EMAIL + ", " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " FROM " + DB_TABLE;
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

           String targetEmail;
           String password = "NOT FOUND";

           if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   targetEmail = cursor.getString(0);

                   if(targetEmail.equals(email)) {
                       password = cursor.getString(1);
                       break;
                   }
               } while(cursor.moveToNext());
           }
           return password;
       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           db.execSQL(queryDrop);
           this.onCreate(db);
       }
   }
   ```
2. And here is the login part.

   ```
   public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

       Button login;
       EditText email, password;
       TextView signuphere;
       MembershipDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MembershipDatabaseHelper(this);

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

           email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_email);
           password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_password);
           login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
           signuphere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signuphere);

           login.setOnClickListener(this);
           signuphere.setOnClickListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(v.getId()) {
           case(R.id.login):

               String enteredEmail = email.getText().toString();
               String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();
               String storedPassword = dbHelper.searchPassword(enteredEmail);

               if(enteredPassword.equals(storedPassword)) {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   finish();
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Email and password don't match.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               break;

           case(R.id.signuphere):
               startActivity(new Intent(this, SignupActivity.class));
               break;
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
       }

       @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setTitle("You haven't finished yet!").setMessage("Are you sure to quit?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   this.close();
               }

               private void close() {
                   finish();
               }   
           }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.cancel();    
               }
           });

           AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
           dialog.show();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send it with the intent , assuming the username is stored in a variable called `username` and your intent is called `welcomeIntent` you can use [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) :

`welcomeIntent.putExtra("username",username);`

and in your activity use :

`Intent.getStringExtra("username");`

By the way check the documentation .. you can use any key instead of `"username"`

**UPDATE**

As you updated your answer with code  this in your `LoginActivity` :

```
    if(enteredPassword.equals(storedPassword)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);

            String username = enteredEmail ; // if it's not the mail then grab the username from ur db

            intent.putExtra("USERNAME_KEY",username);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
  }
```

and then in your `MainScreenActivity` use :

`String username = Intent.getStringExtra("USERNAME_KEY");`

Answer (score 4):

You can use shared preference for this purpose.
SharedPreferences is an API from Android SDK to store and retrieve application preferences. 
SharedPreferences are simply sets of data values that stored persistently and you also available to store data accross all activities in the application package.

When the app use Single Sign On it use SharedPreferences to store access_token, access_expire, username etc. 
After you complete log in with the app, it store some data including access_token and access_expire to the app preferences. 
And when you reopen, it will check the access_token and access_expire values, if access_token return null, the session is no more valid and you have to login again.

```
// To save data in shared preference

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
....

// Set the value of user name in login activity
SharedPreferences settings = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.commit();

// Reading from SharedPreferences
// Use this code to display user name in Second Activity

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
String userName = editor.getString("username", "");

//Remove shared preference
// When you want to close the session use this code
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove("username");
```

Hope this will help you.